# Measuring the risk of an event among hospital patients in survival analysis: should you censor patients who do not have the event?

Tags: survival, biostatistics, censoring, kaplan-meier

I am trying to plot the risk of self-discharge from hospital over time ('self-discharge' means leaving hospital against the wishes of your doctor).

In my data, hospital patients have a duration of stay in days, and a binary flag showing whether they had normal discharge or self-discharge.

Admission durations vary widely, and about 10% of patients self-discharge.

I am unsure if I should be:

1. Using Kaplen-Meier analysis, effectively censoring those who have 'normal discharge'. It seems to ask "among patients remaining in hospital, what is the risk of self-discharge today?", which seems valid but gives a survival much less than 90%. I am not sure if it is appropriate to censor patients when we know they have normal discharge - i.e. it is not uninformative censoring.
2. Plotting the simple cumulative incidence, so that the cumulative risk is 10%. This gives the correct overall risk, but the risk by day appears to reduce as people leave the risk set (in fact the risk is same each day, in this data).

What is the correct approach?

Here is some example data and code using R:

```
library(survival)

# data
set.seed(5)
duration_of_stay <- rpois(10000, 4) + 1
self_discharge <- rbinom(10000, 1, 0.1)

# risk
risk_by_day <- table(duration_of_stay, self_discharge)
cumulative_risk <- cumsum(risk_by_day[,2]) / 10000
plot(1, type = 'n', xlim = c(0, 14), ylim = c(0, 0.2))
lines(1:14, cumulative_risk, type = 's')
sum(self_discharge == 1) / 10000 # risk = 9.75%

# Kaplan-Meier approach
sf <- survfit(Surv(duration_of_stay, self_discharge) ~ 1)
1 - tail(sf$surv, 1) # cumulative incidence = 52.5%
plot(sf, fun = 'event') # kaplan-meier curve
```

Answer (score 1):

We censor an observation (patient) in survival analysis when we have no information regarding the survival status (in this case, whether the patient self-discharged or not) of that observation beyond the censoring date. In your case, a patient cannot both discharge normally and self-discharge. In other words, if a patient discharged normally, it is impossible that that same patient self-discharges beyond the normal discharge date. This means that the normal discharge should be interpreted as a *competing event* of the self discharge. This is why you shouldn't censor a patient when he/she discharged normally. Therefore the cumulative incidence analysis should be used. The risk *should be reduced* as time passes by because more and more people will discharge normally and they are essentially *immune* to the self discharge event from that point on.